# double action link

Tags: html

Can I create a link that has another link in html.
For example, I want to call an html form and the target will be the sidebar frame.
At the same time,  the board frame will also go back to the previous page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as steve mentioned you need a bit of javascript:
`<iframe id="frame1"></iframe>`
`<a href="" onclick="update();return false;" >DoubleActionLink</a>`
`<script>

function update() {

  window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
  parent.document.getElementById('frame1').src="http://www.w3c.org";
 }

</script>`

btw, you said

> I want to call an html form

html form means you'll submit something to web server...so you aren't asking for pure html solution. Isn't ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you would be able to do this in plain HTML, but you could probably use JavaScript to accomplish what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

The w3 specification about links clearly states that this is forbidden ..

[12.2.2 Nested links are illegal](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2)

> Links and anchors defined by the A
>   element must not be nested; an A
>   element must not contain any other A
>   elements.

But you can handle the click event through javascript and do additional actions when clicked..

Answer (score 0):

Use `target="_top"` and set the `href` to the URL of a `<frameset>` document which loads all the frames you want by default.

Better yet, don't use frames. They are more trouble than they are worth.